# Multiprocessing Manager can't be passed to another process

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I need to pass a `Manager` instance to other processes as I need instances of proxy objects created in parallel and later on be re-used again in separate processes. However, it appears that I can' pass a `Manager` as an argument to a function that is ought to be ran by the other process. See an example:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i


def my_fun(i, manager):
    return manager.MyClass(i)


MyManager.register('MyClass', MyClass)
manager = MyManager()
manager.start()
f = partial(my_fun, manager=manager)
with Pool(4) as p:
    res = [r.i for r in p.map(f, list(range(10)))]
print(res)
```

The following exception will arise if I run the code above:

```
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

Interestingly, but passing `Manager` inside of `args` argument of the `Pool.Process` works, but I still need `map` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the proxy that is automatically generated for your class does not support the access of attributes. So if you want to access the `i` attribute of your managed class, you will need to explicitly define your own proxy class. It will be easier to just define, for example, a method `get_i` to return that attribute. I would typically define the `get_i` method in a subclass of the  original class created just for the purpose of being used as the managed class implementation. In the code below I have defined such a method (although I have not bothered to create a special subclass) *and* a custom proxy class to show you how you would do this.

I just see no way of passing the manager instance to another process. The solution I came up with (there may be better ones) is to create a thread that will accept requests via the connections exposed by a `multiprocessing.Pipe` instance. You will need to enforce single threading of these requests not only because you cannot have multiple processes sending to the same connection concurrently but also because it is the only way to ensure that the response a requestor gets back matches up with its request.

The idea is that the `my_fun` function sends via its connection the argument *i* for which it wants to create a `MyClass` instance. A daemon thread running in the main process, function `create_MyClass` for which `manager` is defined, receives this argument, creates the desired class instance and sends the result back. Essentially `create_MyClass` behaves like a factory "method". The manner in which this "method" is "called", i.e. sending a message via a Pipe-created connection to a thread running in a different process, is actually similar to what happens when you make a method call on a managed class's proxy reference.

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
from multiprocessing import Pool, Pipe, Lock
from threading import Thread

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def get_i(self):
        return self.i

class MyClassProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'get_i')

    def get_i(self):
        return self._callmethod('get_i')


def init_pool(the_connection, the_lock):
    global connection, lock
    connection = the_connection
    lock = the_lock

def my_fun(i):
    with lock:
        connection.send(i) # send argument
        my_class = connection.recv() # get result
    return my_class

def create_MyClass(connection):
    while True:
        i = connection.recv()
        my_class = manager.MyClass(i)
        connection.send(my_class)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyManager.register('MyClass', MyClass, MyClassProxy)
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    lock = Lock()
    connection1, connection2 = Pipe(duplex=True)
    # Give one of the bi-directional connections to the daemon thread:
    Thread(target=create_MyClass, args=(connection1,), daemon=True).start()
    # Initialize each process in the pool with the other bi-directional connection
    # and a lock to ensure single-threading of the requests:
    with Pool(4, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(connection2, lock)) as p:
        res = [r.i for r in p.map(my_fun, list(range(10)))]
    print(res)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Did this resolve your problem or is there something you are not clear about?